# Javascript open page in same tab (firefox)?

Tags: javascript, html, firefox

I've been trying to get this right but any of the code i try works.. i looked here and i couldn't find an useful answer.
I have this code on the "onclick" event of a button:

```
function myFunction(){
 window.open("mypage.html","_self");
}
```

that is supposed to open the url in the same tab, but it doesn't do anything. On the other hand if i take out the "_self" argument, it does work but it opens the url in another tab which is exactly what i don't want.

help please?..

Comment: This should work.  Can you point to the actual testcase you're using?

Comment: You should not edit your title to say "Solved".  You should check the checkmark by the answer that best answered your question.  That will indicate to everyone in SO (and to the SO system itself) that your question has been answered and it will count for your own statistics as a question that you asked that was answered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this instead:

```
function myFunction() {
   window.location = "mypage.html";
}
```

This will replace the current document in the current window/tab with a new document loaded from that URL.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to open in the same tab replacing its contents you could perform a redirect:

```
window.location.href = 'mypage.html';
```

Answer (score 0):

you are correct but just to make sure that the target page is in the same location or folder and must be in single quote.

if in the same location/folder then:

```
window.open('target.html';'_self');
```

if in different location/folder then:

```
window.open('folder/target.html';'_self');
```

Hope this works for you.